# Orientation of an object using two curve modifiers

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a Plane with a Box attached that I want to bend with a Curve Modifier. The Plane is zeroed on location and rotation. In order to see the affect I'm moving the Plane to 20mm on the X-axis. That seems to work fine but the Plane is mirrored now (the Box is on the right side now). Why is that?

[image: 01]

[image: 02]

Maybe it has to do with the rotation of the U-Circle but unfortunately I can't apply the rotation on this curve.

If I put this curved Plane on a BezierCurve (combined with an Array-Modifier) it is rotated by 180°. I can change that by tilting the points of the BezierCurve by 180° but I don't understand why this happens in the first place.

[image: 03]

This is how it should look like. Only achived with mirroring my original plane which I want to avoid.

[image: 04]

See the blend-file here:

[image]